# Monotouch: UITableViewCell height

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've been surfing the net to figure out how make my tablecell height fitt its content (my content is of different height).

I've tried to look at this sample .... 
http://simon.nureality.ca/simon-says-project-d-uitableviewcells-autosize-based-on-text-height-in-monotouch-heres-how/
... but I can't make it work.

Here's my code so far .. the cell height is actually working, but the text is centered with trailling dotts (instead of dilling out the entire frame):

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    string item = this.Lst.Items [indexPath.Section];

    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (_cellIdentifier);
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, _cellIdentifier);
        cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, _cellIdentifier);
    }

    // Find the height...
    SizeF textWidth = new SizeF (tableView.Bounds.Width - 40, float.MaxValue);
    SizeF textSize = tableView.StringSize(item, Font, textWidth, LineBreakMode);

    // Textlabel...
    cell.TextLabel.Text = item;
    cell.TextLabel.Font = Font;
    cell.TextLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(cell.TextLabel.Frame.X, cell.TextLabel.Frame.Y, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);

    //cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
    cell.ImageView.Image = PlaceholderImage;   
    cell.EditingAccessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

    // Sizing the cell...
    RectangleF rectCell = cell.Frame;
    rectCell.Height = textSize.Height;
    cell.Frame = rectCell;

    return cell;
}

public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    string item = this.Lst.Items [indexPath.Section];
    SizeF size = new SizeF (tableView.Bounds.Width - 40, float.MaxValue);
    float height = tableView.StringSize (item, Font, size, LineBreakMode).Height + 10;
    return height;
}
```

And it looks like this...

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks!

Mojo

Comment: Is it viable for you to add the UILabel as part of the cell's ContentView? Seems that would be much easier than trying to manipulate it's TextLabel frame.

Comment: Emmm dunno how to do it (this is new to me) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the textlabel's behavior by setting the `Lines` and `LineBreakMode` properties.

For example, setting

```
cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0;
cell.TextLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

will let your label do word wrapping and use as many lines as needed.

Also consider using [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) by Miguel De Icaza. It simplifies dealing with UITableView considerably.

Comment: Thanks - now the text looks fine ... except why does the image have  a left padding when text is heigh?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to "MoveRow" with MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: Havent done it myself, but isn't it just a case of updating your underlying data structure used for the table, i.e. remove element from list and insert it somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah but I need to be able to show the drag handle and the animation when moving the row between other rows. I can't see that i possible in MT.Dialog.