# Change the height of the cell from the Custom class of the cell

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to know if there is any way to change the Height of a custom cell from its own custom class in Xamarin. I know that from the TableSource Class you can use this function to change the Height of the Cell:

```
    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 340;
    }
```

But that would be inefficient in what I am trying to do. I am attempting to Create expanding cells as the amount of text in a textview in a cell gets more text. So it gets bigger based on the amount of data cell.

Comment: You can find height of text and after that you can add this height on your fix cell height.

Comment: @Mohit how would I do this through code could you show me please?

Comment: This is a very complex problem. I suggest you do some research on dynamic cell heights.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344596/monotouch-uitableviewcell-height

I used this question to help answer my question.